# Distance between two points inside two disks of arbitrary radius.

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Given two disks $D_1$ and $D_2$ centered at $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. Let the radius of $D_1$ is $r_1$ and $D_2$ is $r_2$. Assume  that $r_2 > r_1$. Here, both disks can intersect (See Figure ). All $x, p_1,p_2 ,y$ are in a straight line. Can we find a relationvia which we can relate the distance between $x$ and $y$, i.e.,   $d(x,y)$ with the distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$, i.e. , $d(p_1,p_2)$  in both cases without using $r_1$ and $r_2$? Check Note.

PS: If disks are not intersecting, then we can establish $d(p_1,p_2) \geq d(x,y)/2$.

[image]

Comment: If all $x,p_1,p_2,y$ are on the same line then your problem can be reduced to 1 dimension, and $d(x,y) = r_1 + d(p_1,p_2) + r_2$

Comment: What kind of relationship are you looking for? You can always say $d(p_1,p_2) = |d(x,y)-r_1 -r_2|$.

Comment: Without using $r_1, r_2 ?$ No; the distance from $x$ to $y$ depends on the radii $r_1$ and $r_2...$ You can't express $d(x,y)$ without using $r_1,r_2...$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I thought the same. We can only relate if disks are non-intersecting.